# Issues with @types/ckeditor

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm having some issues using @types/ckeditor from the following source.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ckeditor

I've installed the package fine, and then imported the type into the relevant file and all is green in VS code.

```
import "CKEDITOR";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface IEditor {
    editor: CKEDITOR.editor
    addEventHandler(eventName: string, onEvent: Function): void;
    addContextMenuItem(menulabel: string, onEvent: Function): void;
    getTrackingPlugin(): any;
}
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
  })

export class Editor implements IEditor {
  public editor: CKEDITOR.editor

  constructor(rootElement: HTMLElement, config: CKEDITOR.config) {
      this.editor = CKEDITOR.inline(rootElement, config);
  }
}
```

Thats great, however when I do a build, I get the following error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/modules/single-editor/services/editor.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'CKEDITOR' in 'C:\Code\***\src\web\src\app\modules\single-editor\services'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! web@0.0.0 build: `ng build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the web@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-05-07T10_31_08_926Z-debug.log
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1

Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

This code is inside it's own module, I'm on the latest version of Angular, and I'm using ckeditor 4.

Comment: try importing CKEDITOR from @types/ckeditor - import "CKEDITOR" from '@types/ckeditor'

Comment: Unfortunately this producing the following error.

ERROR in src/app/modules/single-editor/services/editor.service.ts(2,19): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/modules/single-editor/services/editor.service.ts(2,24): error TS1005: ';' expected.

Comment: Did you not read and understand the error you just commented? It clearly states that ';' is expected on those lines.

Comment: import { CKEDITOR } from '@types/ckeditor' - I missed curly braces.

Comment: @penleychan It clearly states that yes, but there is also clearly a ';' on the lines in question. I assume the compiler doesn't like the syntax above and thats the error it throws.

Comment: Thanks, @SunilKashyap, I did try that variant as well, and then it complains that "Cannot import type declaration files. Consider importing 'ckeditor' instead of '@types/ckeditor'.ts(6137)". Could it just be that @types/ckeditor doesn't work?

Comment: okay try with import * as CKEDITOR  from 'ckeditor';

Comment: Complaining about it not being a module now 'c:/Code/***/src/web/node_modules/@types/CKEDITOR/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)

Comment: I believe i've found the answer. I needed to include the following. /// <reference types="@types/ckeditor" /> I'd tried this before and it didn't work, the key thing I did wrong though was to not include it at the very beginning of the file, thats essential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe i've found the answer. I needed to include the following.

```
/// <reference types="@types/ckeditor" />
```

I'd tried this before and it didn't work, the key thing I did wrong though was to not include it at the **very beginning of the file**, thats essential.